# Android NDK Debugging

Tags: android, sdk, gdb, android-ndk, gdbserver

The Android NDK documentation doesn't seem all that clear to me as to what sequence of commands you run to get debugging information into, and out of the ndk-gdb executable which is provided.   If there is a format for what lines to break on, and in what file, is there a specification somewhere?  If so, also, how do you give this debugger that information, and through what means?  I'm clueless in every way as to how this process works.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifically addressing "is there a specification somewhere":

ndk-gdb is basically traditional GDB that talks to NDK applications, the GDB documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/ is the best reference for command syntax - it's far too big a topic to cover here.

Comment: ok, i see.. critically it's (in project dir) "ndk-gdb --start", then the commands are referenced in that documentation you described

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of web pages that provide instruction:

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/#more-23

I know others have gotten this to work - but I'm stuck on the issue described here:

[ndk-gdb fails with message: Invalid attribute name:  package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677178/ndk-gdb-invocation-fails-on-macos-connected-to-nexus-one)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://dodotrivia.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-native-code-debugging-with.html) tutorial. It explains how to set up your eclipse environment for debugging NDK code even if this code is part of android library. (Most of the tutorial I found explain only how to setup Eclipse for debugging android application projects that have native code).