# ndk-gdb fails with message: Invalid attribute name:  package

Tags: macos, gdb, android-ndk

Connect Nexus One to Mac running Snow Leopard.
Run "debug" from Eclipse. Shows the execution of

```
/usr/local/android-ndk-r5b/ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1
```

Loads on Nexus One fine. Then I try to run the debugger so I can get to the JNI layer:

```
$ $NDK_DIR/ndk-gdb
```

Fails with these msgs:

```
Invalid attribute name: 
          package
Invalid attribute name: 
          package
Invalid attribute name: 
          package
ERROR: Non-debuggable application installed on the target device.
       Please re-install the debuggable version!
```

So I checked the apk in bin and it has

```
lib/armeabi/gdbserver
```

Looked at the ndk-dbg script, and this message means it's failing trying to find gdbserver on the phone.  So I tried to do some ls commands by hand :

```
$ adb shell ls /data
opendir failed, Permission denied
```

So I looked at /data and the permissions are 771.

What have I done wrong to get to this point?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml file had Windows carriage control (\r\n) which was messing up the ndk-gdb script.  To fix this, I edited the file in vi and did a `"set filetype=unix"`.

Comment: And you can abbreviate as `:set ff=unix` or even as `:se ff=unix`

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to push libs/armeabi/gdbserver to /data/data/your.pkg/lib on a rooted device.