# Debugging Android NDK native apps

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I'm trying to debug and step through an Android application that segfaults. I've tried `ndk-gdb`, but with little luck. I've also referred to [Android NDK Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575885/android-ndk-debugging) without being able to debug my app.

When I try `ndk-gdb --start`, and I get:

```
$ ndk-gdb --start --verbose
Android NDK installation path: /opt/android-ndk-r7
Using default adb command: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
Using final ADB command: '/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb'
Using auto-detected project path: .
Found package name: com.example.native_plasma
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi armeabi-v7a
Device API Level: 10
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi-v7a
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/com.example.native_plasma/lib/gdbserver
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /opt/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a
Found data directory: '/data/data/com.example.native_plasma'
Found first launchable activity: android.app.NativeActivity
Launching activity: com.example.native_plasma/android.app.NativeActivity
## COMMAND: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.example.native_plasma/android.app.NativeActivity
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.native_plasma/android.app.NativeActivity }
## COMMAND: /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb shell sleep 2
Found running PID: 0
ERROR: Could not extract PID of application on device/emulator.
       Weird, this probably means one of these:

         - The installed package does not match your current manifest.
         - The application process was terminated.

       Try using the --verbose option and look at its output for details.
```

This indicates that the application segfaulted more less, but I don't know how to set a breakpoint here since gdb never actually gives a prompt.

I also tried this command:

```
$ ../../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -f -e  libs/armeabi/libnative-plasma.so 
bedb2330
??
??:0
```

I have debug symbols I believe.

- `ndk-build -B V=1 APP_OPTIM=debug`
- `Android.mk` in `jni/` has `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g`
- `ant debug`

I've also `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` but I still get where it looks like I don't have debug symbols.

Here's an image of the stack trace. It doesn't get any more informative:

[image: Traceback]

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but if you're looking for some documentation (it's out of date, mind, as it talks about NDK r5b), then I wrote a guide a few months ago that you can find [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~cb908/AndroidNDK.html). I'm afraid I can't offer any more insight on the problem, except just to check the package name outputted in that log is the same as in the manifest (but I imagine it is, as it found the data directory and stuff)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you used Eclipse. I'm using command-lines. I'm hoping I don't have to use Eclipse. :\

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't think of that. The principles should be the same - as far as I'm aware Eclipse just shows the gdb output, and gives gdb the correct commands (for example when you click the step button) - so no, you don't need to use it. You could try turning off optimisations in the `LOCAL_CFLAGS` (-O0 I think), but I doubt it will do much. How far into the app is your first breakpoint?

Comment: President Evil, I am unable to make a breakpoint because the program exits before I get a gdb prompt.

Comment: I did finally get Eclipse working, but it's no more informative so far.

Comment: The only advantage you might have now is to put a breakpoint in Eclipse right at the beginning of your program, and follow it through until you find where it crashes. But the pid of 0 is odd. Is your app entirely native? It could be an issue with the setup, but I don't know much about that... I don't really know what else to suggest, sorry! (As an aside, I'm happy to see my guide still works!)

Comment: Re: `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g`... `-g` is `-g2`. You might try `-g3`, which includes additional information, like symbolic information such as `#defines`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well NDK_DEBUG=1 and debuggable flag in manifest set to true are required. When you build the app,in your project/libs/armeabi, there should be a gdb.setup file. There is symbol search path there, check whether it is valid. And did you try this:

```
ndk-gdb --start --verbose --force
```

And looks like you are getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: having spent almost half of beautiful sunny san francisco day, i finally came across your answer and voila, my breakpoints are now getting hit with juno after starting gdb as prescribed by you. MANY MANY thanks!!

Comment: @Adnaan could you please give an example of adding "debuggable" flag to the AndroidManifest ? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In latest versions of NDK and Eclipse plug-in you can right click on package and choose **Debug as** -> **Android Native Application**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you load your native library in either a launchable activity or in your Application class. Otherwise it wouldn't work and you'll get the following error `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`.

For example in Application class:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Name");
    }

    public static native int doSomething();
}
```

Name is the name of your library (.so file) without the lib part.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved putting **--nowait** option to the shell command:

```
ndk-gdb --start --verbose --nowait
```