# How to debug a native Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've installed the [Sequoyah Android Native Support](http://www.tag-games.com/2012/06/05/native-android-debugging-in-eclipse/), and now, I can execute the debug mode. I have a breakpoint in the same line where I call a native method, so when I execute the debug Java mode, eclipse stops in this line, I execute the 'ndk-gdb', and I lunch the C/C++ debug mode, I see the console do something. But, how can I put C breakpoints? Because my C code is a .so library, so I can't put breakpoints in this file. I have a JNI floder where there are .c and .h files, but don't stops when I put breakpoints. Eclipse log recognizes breakpoints, but prints error.

break-insert com_example_pruebaffmpeg_MainActivity.c:4323
error, msg="No symbol table is loaded. Use the \"file\" command."

Comment: Did you compile your C code with the debug info/symbols included?  If you are compiling with GCC, make sure you include `-g` option on both compiling and linking steps.

Comment: I don't know what you explain me. I'm using the ndk-build to compile my C code and obtain a .so library. And I run the Android project in Eclipse with the NDK tool.

Comment: For ndk-build there are other steps that you need to take to build with debugging symbols.  Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934575/debugging-android-ndk-native-apps)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uninstalling Sequoyah and just using the ADT?  As of version 20, the [Eclipse ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) can debug NDK projects more easily and reliably than the old Sequoyah way of doing things.

Comment: I've uninstalled the Sequoyah and I've tried to launch the debugger using the ADT, but it doesn't run. Could you explain a little more that or post a link?

Comment: I'm following the instructions on this [link](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin), but the debugger doesn't work

Comment: And console print this error ---->
warning: while parsing target library list (at line 2): No segment defined for /system/bin/linker
BFD: /home/beni/workspace/Prueba/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/linker: warning: sh_link not set for section `.ARM.exidx'
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 63 libraries, e.g. libstdc++.so.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Comment: If you get the error: **"warning: sh_link not set for section `.ARM.exidx'"** and **"WARNING: Could not load native library: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "__exidx_end"** referenced by [...]" on **Android 4.2.x** try what is written here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501998/313113