# Standalone C application crashes on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, native

I created simple standalone C application on Android

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("Hello, world!n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it using makefile

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := myexe
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Native.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -fuse-ld=bfd
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

After copying and running it on emulator I get error message:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: cannot locate symbol "__exidx_end" referenced by "./myexe"...
```

What is wrong in my makefile?

Comment: I believe this is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555376/cocos2d-x-game-fresh-off-the-play-store-cant-even-open/14501998#14501998

Comment: Great! Works :) Thank you