# Debug native library in Android

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, android-library

I want to debug and put breakpoints into my C++ library.
My work space right now is like this:

```
/-Main App
/-Library1 (just Android library)
/-NativeLibrary
```

MainApp has included both libraries, Library1 and NativeLibrary, and I want to be able to put breakpoints into my NativeLibrary.
I followed this post this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483445 but when I try to select my MainApp as Project I can't do it.

So, how can I debug my own native library?

Comment: This is just a suggestion, not a solution to your problem in a direct manner. Native debugging in Eclipse seemed really messy to me. Maybe I was doing something wrong or the problem was with Eclipse. I switched to Nvidia Nsight on Visual Studio and it is far more stable and easy to use. I don't know if you want to go that route but Nvidia tools are promising.

Comment: And make sure your libraries are not stripped. I mean, they have the debug information.

Comment: Agree with @user2359247 that native debugging in Eclipse is really messy. Especially if its not a "pure" NDK application. I've had a lot of luck with ndk-gdb on the command line, and colleagues of mine swear by the Nvidia solution.

Comment: @user2359247 thanks for the advice and krsteev thanks too to comment. It's amazing that this is so difficult to do in eclipse. Anyway, I'm going to try with Visual Studio and nVidia, but I want to find a solution for this.