# Debugging native code in library project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-library, ndk-gdb

I am trying to debug my android application which make use of a library that has native code.
I looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library) and configured the ndk debugger as mentioned in it and was able to start the debugger but i am not able to step through the breakpoints i set.
And before starting the debugger i get this warning :

> Error while mapping shared library sections:
>   `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so':
>    not in executable format: File format not recognized
>
> warning: .dynamic section for "/home/raneez/Documents/android/workspace/SmartCardLibrary/obj/local/armeabi/libcrypto.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
>
> warning: .dynamic section for "/home/raneez/Documents/android/workspace/SmartCardLibrary/obj/local/armeabi/libssl.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
>
> warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 120 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
>   Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
>
> Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
>   warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
>   GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
>   that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
>   or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
>
> [New Thread 13826]
>
> [New Thread 13827]
>
> [New Thread 13828]
>
> [New Thread 13829]
>
> [New Thread 13833]
>
> [New Thread 13834]
>
> [New Thread 13835]
>
> [New Thread 13837]
>
> [New Thread 13838]
>
> [New Thread 13850]
>
> [New Thread 13852]

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the libjpeg.so file you're using, it's compiled for x86_64 desktop linux but you need a version recompiled for the Android architecture you're running on (armeabi-v7a, x86, etc).

Regarding the other warnings for libcrypto.so and libssl.so libs. The ones used are those from the device, not from your application. You're fine with these.