# How to set breakpoint in Android native C shared library code?

Tags: android, c, debugging, java-native-interface, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug native C code in a shared library on Android (in Windows) but none of my breakpoints are hit.
I tried 
http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

I tried different debug configurations as suggested here: 
[Debug native code in Android Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library)
but it didn't work. On console I get:

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 92 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Alex

Comment: Are you getting that warning because your native library has been stripped of debug symbols?

Comment: No, I didn't strip any symbols from the library. Thanks.