# How to "step into" C function in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio

Using the standard Hello-jni NDK example, I am trying to "Step Into" a C function in Android Studio. However the debugger denies any attempt to enter into the stringFromJNI() function, which is done by pressing the F7 function key. It simply step over instead.

```
    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);
    // how to step into stringFromJNI() function?
 => String s = stringFromJNI();
    tv.setText( s );
    setContentView(tv);
```

Does anybody know how to do cross-language debugging in Android Studio?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do native debugging in Android Studio 1.0. It's not implemented. If you're using Eclipse, there's some help at [Debug native code in Android Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library) but this hasn't been done in Android Studio yet.