# How to debug prebuild shared library on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I compile a project using prebuild shared libraries (compiled elsewhere), that I want to debug in Android Studio.

I tried to copy the library source code into my Android Studio project, and use them to make breakpoints, but it's not working. It cannot find the position to put it (pending breakpoint). The prebuild libraries are well debugging compiled, but elsewhere.

How can I include library source files into my android studio project, and used them to debug my prebuild libraries during application execution?

Comment: This is a duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638849/debug-native-code-in-android-library

Comment: I am on Android Studio, i don't want to recreate the project on Eclipse