# Cannot debug native code under Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

Environment: Latest NDK + Eclipse Juno + ADT + CDT. Everything is up to date.

When I try to debug my Android application natively, I get the following error:

```
 warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
 GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
 that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
 or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
```

To ensure it is not my specific application, I created a simple dummy application. Here are the steps I took.

1. From Eclipse, create a new Android application project (with min-sdk 16 and target-sdk 21)
2. Added a class:

```java
package com.test.mytest1;

public class MyNative {
    static {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        System.loadLibrary("mytest1");
    }
    native public static void init();
}
```

Note that I have added a line to wait for the debugger to initialize.

3. Called MyNative.init() from MainActivity's onCreate() method.
4. From preferences, fixed NDK to point to C:\adt\ndk directory.
5. From the project menu, selected Android Tools-->Add Native Support.
6. From Properties->C++ Build, set build command to "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1"
7. Here is the code in mytest1.cpp:

```java
static int x = 0;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_mytest1_MyNative_init(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{
    x++;
}
```

8. Added Application.mk in jni directory:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a 
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

Now, when I try to run the app as native application, it fails with the above mentioned message.

When I look at the apk file, lib/armeabi-v7a does contain gdbserver as well as libmytest1.so files.

The app does work. If I add a log() statement in my native method, it does get displayed in LogCat.

I am confused and tired. A simple thing like thing should just work. Wondering if you can share what you did differently to make it work. Regards.

Comment: Its odd (to me) to place `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` in a static initializer. When needed, I usually place it in `onCreate`. I'm not sure it matters for your problem, though.

Comment: Related: [Debugging Android NDK native apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934575/debugging-android-ndk-native-apps). But I'm not sure if the methods apply to shared objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger() is for JAVA debugging.
2. To debug Native code add sleep(seconds) before your first breakpoint , that's way gdb  have to to connect gdbserver

   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_mytest1_MyNative_init(JNIEnv *, jclass)
   {
       sleep(10);
       x++;
   }